# Ошибка "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined" при добавлении в массив

Tags: javascript

Пишу небольшую программку для себя, в результате выполнения получаю ошибку

> Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

при добавлении в массив. Из-за чего она появляется, и как её исправить?

```js
console.log(flatList([
  [
    [2]
  ],
  [4, [5, 6, [6], 6, 6, 6], 7]
]));

function flatList(array) {
  let res;
  array.forEach(el => {
    res = repeat(el);
  });
  return res;
}

var tmp = tmp || [];

function repeat(itms) {
  if (typeof itms === 'number') {
    tmp.push(itms);
  } else {
    itms.forEach(el => repeat(el));
  }
}
```

Comment: при выполнении сниппета нет указанной ошибки.

Comment: @Grundy попробуйте выполнить код из консоли, ответ мне уже предложили, но почему мой код выдает эту странную ошибку до сих пор не понятен

Comment: что в консоли, что в сниппете - указанной ошибки нет.

Comment: @Grundy в консоли браузера, почему то местный редактор не отображает ошибку

Comment: редактор не отображает ошибку - потому что ее нет. Если она есть у тебя - значит у тебя другой код.

Comment: @Grundy  а так   http://prntscr.com/l8url6

Comment: А вот так и надо было вставлять в вопрос. Проблема в том, что ты `flatList` вызываешь до того, как в переменную массив запишешь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот рабочая версия, хотя вторую проверку на число можно и убрать.

```
function flatList(arr){
    let res = [];
    arr.forEach(el => {
        repeat(el,res);
    });
    return res;
}
function repeat(itms,arr){
    if(typeof itms === 'number'){
        arr.push(itms);
    }else{
        itms.forEach(el => {
            if(typeof el === 'number')
                arr.push(el);
            else
                repeat(el,arr);
        });
    }
}
console.log(flatList([[[2]], [4, [5, 6, [6], 6, 6, 6], 7]]));
```

Answer (score 3):

Проблема заключается в том, что вызов функции `flatList` происходит **до** того, как присвоилось значение в переменную `tmp`.

Поэтому внутри функции, эта переменная будет `undefined`, и будет возникать указанная ошибка.

Для решения, нужно присваивать значение `tmp` **до** вызова функции, в которой используется эта переменная:

```
var tmp = tmp || [];
...
console.log(flatList([
  [
    [2]
  ],
  [4, [5, 6, [6], 6, 6, 6], 7]
]));
```

Answer (score 2):

Ошибки, про которую Вы пишите, - нет.

Функция `repeat` ничего не возвращает.

Comment: запустите из консоли, местный редактор этого не показывает, в предложенном ответе к этой задаче ф-я repeat тоже ничего не возвращает